# How do I avoid repetitiveness?

Tags: java

Im doing a tutorial in Java and I always read that I must try not to be repetitive and I noticed this is very repetitive; So if anyone can give me some tips to make it less repetitive or somehow better it is much appriciated. Thanks ;) (This isn't part of the the tutorial, I made it just for fun because of what I am learning in science at school)

1. **Run.java** file:

   ```
   package scientificFormula;

   public class Run {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Formula formula = new Formula();

           formula.compound1 = args[0];
           formula.compound2 = args[1];

           String theFormula = formula.createFormula();
           System.out.println("Molecule: " + args[0] + " " + args[1] + " = "
                   + theFormula);
       }

   }
   ```
2. **Formula.java** file:

   ```
   package scientificFormula;

   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Map;

   public class Formula {
       String compound1;
       String compound2;
       static private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

       static private void initiateIons() {
           // 1+
           map.put("Hydrogen", "H^1+");
           map.put("Lithium", "Li^1+");
           map.put("Sodium", "Na^1+");
           map.put("Potassium", "K^1+");
           map.put("Rubidium", "Rb^1+");
           // 2+
           map.put("Magnesium", "Mg^2+");
           map.put("Calcium", "Ca^2+");
           map.put("Strontium", "Sr^2+");
           // 3+
           map.put("Aluminium", "Al^3+");
           // 3-
           map.put("Nitrogem", "N^-3");
           map.put("Phosphorus", "P^-3");
           // 2-
           map.put("Oxygen", "O^-2");
           map.put("Sulfur", "S^-2");
           map.put("Selenium", "Se^-2");
           // 1-
           map.put("Fluorine", "F^-1");
           map.put("Chlorine", "Cl^-1");
           map.put("Bromine", "Br^-1");
           map.put("Iodine", "I^-1");
       }

       String createFormula() {
           initiateIons();

           // Example1: Input = Calcium Iodine:
           // 2x + -1y = 0
           // x = 1 and y = 2
           // Output = CaI2
           //
           // Example2: Input = Sulfur Iodine
           // Output = Molecule: Sulfur Iodine = SI2

           String symbol1 = map.get(compound1);
           String symbol2 = map.get(compound2);

           int charge1 = Integer.parseInt(symbol1.replace("+", "").substring(
                   symbol1.length() - 2));
           int charge2 = Integer.parseInt(symbol2.replace("+", "").substring(
                   symbol2.length() - 2));

           String letter1 = null;
           String letter2 = null;

           if (symbol1.length() == 5) {
               letter1 = symbol1.substring(0, 2);
           } else if (symbol1.length() == 4) {
               letter1 = symbol1.substring(0, 1);
           }
           if (symbol2.length() == 5) {
               letter2 = symbol2.substring(0, 2);
           } else if (symbol2.length() == 4) {
               letter2 = symbol2.substring(0, 1);
           }

           int possitive1 = (int) Math.sqrt(charge1 * charge1);
           int possitive2 = (int) Math.sqrt(charge2 * charge2);

           if ((possitive1 == 1) & (possitive2 == 1)) {
               return letter1 + letter2;
           } else if (possitive1 == 1) {
               return letter1 + possitive2 + letter2;
           } else if (possitive2 == 1) {
               return letter1 + letter2 + possitive1;
           }
           if (possitive1 == 0) {
               possitive1 = -(charge1);
           }

           if (possitive2 == 0) {
               possitive2 = -(charge2);
           }

           return letter1 + possitive2 + letter2 + possitive1;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Which piece do you find repetitive?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the parts at the bottom - under `createFormula()` (a bit hidden - it requires scrolling)

Comment: You could only really replace some one-liners to a method call

Comment: Firstly, You can add methods to pass `symbol` as String and return `charge` int value. Second, you can have to get String return letter. and Third method you can have to return positive int value.
This can replace your current code to certain method calls.

Comment: Why have people downvoted this question? Could you tell me why? How could I research this question for my specific code? I did actually spend a while fixing it up (used to be way more repetitive) Also thanks for the useful comments :)

Comment: What is this meant to do:`int possitive1 = (int) Math.sqrt(charge1 * charge1);`?? There's `Math.abs()`.

Comment: Another one: You can avoid this antiquated '^'. Unicode! For instance: `I⁻¹ Sr²⁺`.  `"I\u207B\u00B9 Sr\u00B2\u207A"`

Comment: There's room for more improvement, but I'll have to understand it in full before I write something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend reading the book [clean code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) which mainly deals with refactoring.

Duplicating code is just one (important) issue when you start refactoring (also called **DRY** - Don't Repeat Yourself). There are many other principles and I'll try describe a few of them which I find most important:

One important "rule of thumb" is the **SRP**: Single Responsibility Principle, which says that each class should have only one responsibility, and if we apply the same idea to methods - each method should do only one thing! It might sound very strict, but when you'll start applying it - your code will become clearer to read and easier to maintain.

Another one is using meaningful names (classes/methods/variables):

```
return letter1 + possitive2 + letter2; // you probably meant positive with one 's' (typo!)
```

might mean something to you - but it will not mean much to another reader - now, of course you can solve it by adding code comments, but that's patching the problem instead of solving it. Further, code comments get stale - either become irrelevant or even worse - might mislead the reader when the code changes and the comment doesn't.

And last (for now), keep clear order of execution, let's take a piece of code that you posted and improve it:

```
    String symbol1 = map.get(compound1);
    String symbol2 = map.get(compound2);

    int charge1 = Integer.parseInt(symbol1.replace("+", "").substring(
            symbol1.length() - 2));
    int charge2 = Integer.parseInt(symbol2.replace("+", "").substring(
            symbol2.length() - 2));

    String letter1 = null;
    String letter2 = null;

    if (symbol1.length() == 5) {
        letter1 = symbol1.substring(0, 2);
    } else if (symbol1.length() == 4) {
        letter1 = symbol1.substring(0, 1);
    }
    if (symbol2.length() == 5) {
        letter2 = symbol2.substring(0, 2);
    } else if (symbol2.length() == 4) {
        letter2 = symbol2.substring(0, 1);
    }

    int possitive1 = (int) Math.sqrt(charge1 * charge1);
    int possitive2 = (int) Math.sqrt(charge2 * charge2);
```

As we can see: positive depends on charge which depends on symbol which depends on compound. And totaly unrelated to it: letter depends on symbol which depends on compound.

let's split it to separate methods:

```
int getPositive(String compound) { // I have no idea what "positive", "symbol" and compound represent, consider better names please
    String symbol = map.get(compound);
    int charge = Integer.parseInt(symbol.replace("+", "").substring(
                symbol.length() - 2));
    return (int) Math.sqrt(charge2 * charge2);
}
```

And now we can apply the same to `getLetter(String compound) {...}` etc.

Comment: Thankyou so so much. Probably the best answer here. I thought about putting something into different methods, but when I tried it, there was errors about local variables and stuff so I just decided not to. I'll carry on with my tutorial as this was something fun and I'll try and buy that book - hehe the description looks interesting. (Im very very new to java. Started about 4 weeks ago.)

Comment: @gogobebe2 in your favor (besides the fact that you just started) I must say that I got the impression that you're very organized and consistent. These two qualities will serve you well if you'll decide to dive into the world of programming!

Comment: Thankyou so much. That really does mean a lot. I want my job to be programming of some kind when I grow up :)

Answer (score 2):

I would throw some of that parsing into its own class, maybe you can even offload more into there when you build out more functionallity.

```
public class Symbol {
    final int charge;
    final String letter;
    public Symbol(String str) {
        int sepIndex = str.indexOf('^');
        if(sepIndex != -1) {
            letter = str.substring(0, sepIndex);
            charge = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(sepIndex+1).replace("+", ""));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(str + " isnt a valid Symbol, no ^ found");
        }
    }
}

public class Formula {
    String compound1;
    String compound2;
    static private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // make this a static block so its only called once.
    static {
        // 1+
        map.put("Hydrogen", "H^1+");
        map.put("Lithium", "Li^1+");
        map.put("Sodium", "Na^1+");
        map.put("Potassium", "K^1+");
        map.put("Rubidium", "Rb^1+");
        // 2+
        map.put("Magnesium", "Mg^2+");
        map.put("Calcium", "Ca^2+");
        map.put("Strontium", "Sr^2+");
        // 3+
        map.put("Aluminium", "Al^3+");
        // 3-
        map.put("Nitrogem", "N^-3");
        map.put("Phosphorus", "P^-3");
        // 2-
        map.put("Oxygen", "O^-2");
        map.put("Sulfur", "S^-2");
        map.put("Selenium", "Se^-2");
        // 1-
        map.put("Fluorine", "F^-1");
        map.put("Chlorine", "Cl^-1");
        map.put("Bromine", "Br^-1");
        map.put("Iodine", "I^-1");
    }
    String createFormula() {

        // Example1: Input = Calcium Iodine:
        // 2x + -1y = 0
        // x = 1 and y = 2
        // Output = CaI2
        //
        // Example2: Input = Sulfur Iodine
        // Output = Molecule: Sulfur Iodine = SI2

        Symbol symbol1 = new Symbol(map.get(compound1));
        Symbol symbol2 = new Symbol(map.get(compound2));

        int possitive1 = Math.abs(symbol1.charge); // sqrt(a*a) == abs(a)
        int possitive2 = Math.abs(symbol1.charge);

        if ((possitive1 == 1) & (possitive2 == 1)) {
            return symbol1.letter + symbol1.letter;
        } else if (possitive1 == 1) {
            return symbol1.letter + possitive2 + symbol2.letter;
        } else if (possitive2 == 1) {
            return symbol1.letter + symbol2.letter + possitive1;
        }

        // dead code, if positive1 is 0 then setting it to -0 does nothing
        /*if (possitive1 == 0) {
            possitive1 = -(symbol1.charge);
        }
        if (possitive2 == 0) {
            possitive2 = -(symbol2.charge);
        }*/

        return symbol1.letter + possitive2 + symbol2.letter + possitive1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. The stackoverflow community is so amazing how generous in time they are! :D

Comment: I have no idea why I did if (possitive2 == 0) lol

Answer (score 1):

First method:

```
getCharge(String symbol){
       return Integer.parseInt(symbol.replace("+", "").substring(symbol.length() - 2));
}
```

Second Method:

```
getLetter(String symbol){
    if (symbol.length() == 5) {
        return symbol.substring(0, 2);
    } else if (symbol.length() == 4) {
        return symbol.substring(0, 1);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is equivalent to your posted code -

```
private static String checkCompound(String symbol) {
  if (symbol.length() == 5) {
    return symbol.substring(0, 2);
  } else if (symbol.length() == 4) {
    return symbol.substring(0, 1);
  }
  return "";
}
```

Then

```
String letter1 = checkCompound(symbol1);
String letter2 = checkCompound(symbol2);

if (charge1 > 0) {
  if (charge2 > 0) {
    return letter1 + letter2;
  }
  return letter1 + charge2 + letter2;
} else if (charge2 > 0) {
  return letter1 + letter2 + charge1;
}

return letter1 + charge2 + letter2 + charge1;
```

Finally, this

```
if (possitive1 == 0) {
  possitive1 = -(charge1);
}
```

was removed because it's `-0` which is `0`.

Comment: @gogobebe2 Okay. `int possitive1 = (int) Math.sqrt(charge1 * charge1)` tell us that possitive1 == charge1. Why? What is the squareroot of `2 * 2`, `3 * 3`, `n * n`? Were you expecting it to be the absolute value?

Comment: @gogobebe2 Why would -(0) be positive? Also, what was `Math.sqrt(charge1 * charge1)` for?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first let's rearrange your code so that all of the ...1 variables are together. Judging by your naming convention, you use letter1 to calculate symbol1, symbol1 to calculate charge1, etc... I'm just going to focus on createFormula() since that's the part you want to reduce in size.

```
String createFormula() {
    initiateIons();

    //Calculate symbol1, charge1, letter1, possitive1
    String symbol1 = map.get(compound1);
    int charge1 = Integer.parseInt(symbol1.replace("+", "").substring(
            symbol1.length() - 2));
    String letter1 = null;
    if (symbol1.length() == 5) {
        letter1 = symbol1.substring(0, 2);
    } else if (symbol1.length() == 4) {
        letter1 = symbol1.substring(0, 1);
    }
    int possitive1 = (int) Math.sqrt(charge1 * charge1);

    //calculate symbol2, charge2, letter2, possitive2
    String symbol2 = map.get(compound2);
    int charge2 = Integer.parseInt(symbol2.replace("+", "").substring(
            symbol2.length() - 2));
    String letter2 = null;
    if (symbol2.length() == 5) {
        letter2 = symbol2.substring(0, 2);
    } else if (symbol2.length() == 4) {
        letter2 = symbol2.substring(0, 1);
    }
    int possitive2 = (int) Math.sqrt(charge2 * charge2);

    //Returns
    if ((possitive1 == 1) & (possitive2 == 1)) {
        return letter1 + letter2;
    } else if (possitive1 == 1) {
        return letter1 + possitive2 + letter2;
    } else if (possitive2 == 1) {
        return letter1 + letter2 + possitive1;
    }
    if (possitive1 == 0) {
        possitive1 = -(charge1);
    }

    if (possitive2 == 0) {
        possitive2 = -(charge2);
    }

    return letter1 + possitive2 + letter2 + possitive1;
}
```

I agree, the calculation step seems redundant. It would be amazing to have a function that calculates those for and returns a tuple of them, but (as far as I know) Java doesn't yet have tuples. We can do a string array though, and parse the ints back out of the strings. Here's a less redundant revision of your code.

```
String[] calculatePieces(String compound){
    String symbol = map.get(compound);
    int charge = Integer.parseInt(symbol.replace("+", "").substring(
            symbol.length() - 2));
    String letter = null;
    if (symbol.length() == 5) {
        letter = symbol1.substring(0, 2);
    } else if (symbol1.length() == 4) {
        letter = symbol1.substring(0, 1);
    }
    int possitive = (int) Math.sqrt(charge * charge);
    pieces = new String[4];
    pieces[0] = symbol;
    pieces[1] = charge + "";
    pieces[2] = letter;
    pieces[3] = possitive + "";
    return pieces;
}

String createFormula() {
    initiateIons();

    String[] pieces1 = calculatePieces(compound1);
    int charge1 = Integer.parseInt(pieces1[1]);
    int possitive1 = Integer.parseInt(pieces1[3]);
    String[] pieces2 = calculatePieces(compound2);
    int charge2 = Integer.parseInt(pieces2[1]);
    int possitive2 = Integer.parseInt(pieces2[3]);

    //Returns
    if ((possitive1 == 1) & (possitive2 == 1)) {
        return pieces1[2] + pieces2[2];
    } else if (possitive1 == 1) {
        return pieces1[2] + possitive2 + pieces2[2];
    } else if (possitive2 == 1) {
        return pieces1[2] + pieces2[2] + possitive1;
    }
    if (possitive1 == 0) {
        possitive1 = -(charge1);
    }

    if (possitive2 == 0) {
        possitive2 = -(charge2);
    }

    return pieces1[2] + possitive2 + pieces2[2] + possitive1;
}
```

It's a bit better, but Java's restriction on returning a single object limits how clean this can get. The way to make it even cleaner is to make a wrapper object that basically acts as a tuple of (string, int, string, int), but if you need this to be fast that's not the way to go.

Comment: Very good answer thankyou very much for taking time out of your day.